# How to validate every instance in an array with any definition in JSON schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I need to validate following array items.

```
{
    contents: [{
        type: "text",
        content: "This is text context"
    }, {
        type: "image",
        content: "http://image.url"
    }]
}
```

I need to validate every item in the contents array.

Content objects should each have `type` and `content` properties. 
`type` can be "text", "image" or "video".
For image or video, `content` should be a valid url.

For that I wrote following schema.

```
{
    "id": "post",
    "description": "generell schema for a post",
    "definitions": {
        "contents": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "allOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/text" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/image" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/video" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/mention" }
                ]
            }
        },
        "text": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {"enum": ["text"]},
                "content": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": [
                "content",
                "type"
            ]
        },
        "image": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {"enum": ["image"]},
                "content": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "format": "url"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "content",
                "type"
            ]
        },
        "video": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {"enum": ["video"]},
                "content": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "format": "url"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "content",
                "type"
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

But above JSON is not valid with my schema. It said `data.contents[0].type should be equal to one of the allowed values`

If i use oneOf instead of allOf it is valid. But image content can be string without valid URL.

What is the correct schema?

Comment: and the question is.... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you are using `allOf` when you should be using `oneOf`.

The root item also needs a properties definition. Hopefully the below changes helps you get the solution you require or point you in the right direction.

```
{
    "id": "post",
    "description": "generell schema for a post",
    "properties": {
        "contents": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/text" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/image" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/video" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/mention" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    "definitions": {
        "text": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {"enum": ["text"]},
                "content": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": [
                "content",
                "type"
            ]
        },
        "image": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {"enum": ["image"]},
                "content": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "format": "url"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "content",
                "type"
            ]
        },
        "video": {
            "properties": {
                "type": {"enum": ["video"]},
                "content": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "format": "url"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "content",
                "type"
            ]
        }
    }

}
```